# google apps script open new document

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, document, google-docs-api

hi want to create a google document and add to the value of the variable which is. Why can't I pass it to a document with this function?

```
var doc=DocumentApp.create("Wynik"); 
doc.getBody().appendParagraph(arr[wasitfound]);
```

> error code: "Exception: The parameters (number[]) don't match the
> method signature for DocumentApp.Body.appendParagraph."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the documentation for [appendParagraph](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body).

It accepts a **string** but you are passing an **array**.

Example:

```
var str = "Hello";
doc.getBody().appendParagraph(str)
```

or use [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join):

```
doc.getBody().appendParagraph(arr[wasitfound].join())
```

Comment: i have in str `[ Sat Oct 23 2021 23:58:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time),
  1.1642 ]` and wants to throw it into the newly created document.   The question is how can I put it in there?? :D